# Load Excel data into a views - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a view - called as View A and three other tables - Table A, Table B and Table c.

Table A , Table B, Table C are connected to each other through Primary and foreign Keys.

Then I created a View called as View A with column fields coming from those tables. I have the same columns available in my excel sheet. How, do I load that data inside the view. So, that the tables get updated.

Note : - SQL Server Import Wizard didn't show the view created. It just showed the 3 tables.

Comment: You cannot directly insert into a view and trigger insertion into underlying tables. The opposite is true, you can insert into underlying tables and expect the data to be reflected into your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view is a virtual table. A view consists of rows and columns just like a table. The difference between a view and a table is that views are definitions built on top of other tables (or views), and do not hold data themselves. If data is changing in the underlying table, the same change is reflected in the view.

Because a view is virtual you're unable to insert data into them without that data being present in the underlining tables first.